# OpenGL Batch render Mesh

Tags: opengl, mesh, glew, 3d-modelling

I'm using OpenGL, glew and GLFW to code a simple game for a project. I already have a 3D model importer using Assimp and it is handling textures as well.

This is the way I'm drawing one mesh:

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[NORMAL_VB]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[TEXCOORD_VB]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[POS_VB]);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);

    //Render the triangles
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_Entries[i].NumIndices);
```

My question is how can I render hundred of moving entities using this same mesh but each one has a different world position and rotation?

If I have hundreds of moving entities, each frame I'm rendering the same mesh hundreds of times and I can notice the FPS drop now.

Btw, I'm not using shaders, just simple draw

Comment: That is what vertex shaders and instancing are for. The problem is because you are using `glVertexPointer (...)`, etc. I really have no idea what version of GL you are using; instancing was promoted to core in GL 3.1, but this code could be as old as GL 1.5. Can you mention what version of GL you are using to make writing an answer simpler?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, actually I really don't know what version I'm using but it's maybe the last one, I dont know

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, I'm still using a lot of old and deprecated functions

Comment: Well, are you using shaders at all? That is a good place to start. There are techniques you can use for instancing even when there is no support from GL, but they require at the very least vertex shaders.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: I second that. By using shaders and learning how to write them (notably the vertex shader), he would have a natural answer to his question. (simply issue multiple draw calls after setting a new world matrix in the uniform buffer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `glVertexPointer()` (and the other `gl<Foo>Pointer()` calls) are deprecated in OpenGL 3 and later, I'm assuming that you're not currently using an OpenGL 3+ core profile.

There are two methods of instanced rendering which are potentially available, both provided via extensions;  [ARB_Draw_Instanced](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/draw_instanced.txt) and [ARB_Instanced_Arrays](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/instanced_arrays.txt).  Either, both, or neither might be available on any particular card/driver.

**ARB_Draw_Instanced** provides `glDrawArraysInstancedARB()`, which works basically like the `glDrawArrays` call you're already using, but also provides a `gl_InstanceId` integer variable for use in your shaders, which you can then use to read matrices or whatever other per-instance data you need from a UBO, TBO, or whatever other mechanism you want to use to get that per-instance data into the shader.  In theory, this extension could be available in a context as early as OpenGL 1.1.

**ARB_Instanced_Arrays** provides `glVertexAttribDivisorARB()`, which lets you modify the way that particular vertex attributes work.  In a vertex shader each subsequent vertex normally gets the next attribute value from the attached buffer.  So the first vertex gets the position specified first in the buffer, the second vertex gets the second position, and so on.  With this function, you can tell OpenGL to instead advance the data being provided to the shader according to instances, instead of according to vertices.  So you can, for example, create a generic vertex attribute containing the world positions of all the instances which are going to be drawn, and tell OpenGL to only update that value between instances, so every vertex of the first instance gets the first value, every vertex of the second instance gets the second value, and so on.  From the shader's point of view, these values are now treated as if they were vertex attributes, instead of as uniforms.  In theory, this extension could be available in a context as early as OpenGL 2.

On my hardware, neither of these approaches are usable in an OpenGL 2.1 context (as these extensions, or related ones, aren't exposed).  Your computer may be like mine;  incapable of doing instanced rendering in an OpenGL 2.1 context.  Or yours might support both approaches.  Or just one or the other.  Likewise, anyone else you give your program to might find that their computer supports one or the other or both or neither.  Extensions are like that, and your program should be able to cope, no matter what the host computer supports.

In my case, rather than deal with separate implementations depending on what the computer supported, the 'easy' solution was to switch to an OpenGL 3+ context, where both interfaces are available in non-extension form.

`glDrawArraysInstanced()` (the non-extension version of the above ARB interface) became core in OpenGL 3.1, so is guaranteed to be present in every 3.1 core profile.  Similarly, `glVertexAttribDivisor()` was added to the core profile in OpenGL 3.3, and will be available in every 3.3 core profile.

Comment: What makes you think this is OpenGL 2.1, out of curiosity? The only things I see are Vertex Arrays (OpenGL 1.1) and Buffer Objects (OpenGL 1.5).

Comment: might be a serious MacOsX bias. 2.1 has been the super default for a good decade.

Comment: Hm, true.  (And in retrospect, I've *written* OpenGL 1.x code which used vertex arrays and checked whether buffer objects were supported)  In which case, I'll add that ARB_Instanced_Arrays could potentially be available as far back as OpenGL 1.1, whereas ARB_Draw_Instanced (since it requires programmable shaders to be useful) requires at least OpenGL 2.

Comment: hardware instancing is all cute and all, but brings nothing to improve performance if the rendered mesh is something more than a cube. write combine memory is used to stream commands to the graphic card, multiple draw calls are well pipeplined and don't cause enough overhead to see a win in the case of a mesh model picturing a human which must have at least a thousand triangles.

Comment: @v.oddou In modern computer graphics, performance is never as simple as you're implying.